# WordPress File Extensions

Tags: mod-rewrite, wordpress

I am converting a Frankenstein monster of a website into a Wordpress.  The first challenge I am facing is to keep our old URLs for Google. this site has several .PHP pages and several HTML pages.

Our Google ranking is high in several key search terms. So it is important to me that page addresses remain the same.  So far I cannot find a plugin which would allow my Wordpress site to have both .HTML and .PHP permalinks.

I am familiar with mod_rewrite() and have used it before, but when I inserted a rewrite rule into the existing Wordpress .htacces file, it broke the routing altogether.

I would greatly appreciate any input from your Wordpress gurus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `301 redirect` and here's an example `.htaccess`.

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage2.html http://www.yoursite.com/folder/
```